# Can Aperture auto-delete photos after import from an iPhone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, photos, aperture

I'm trying out Aperture to see whether I should upgrade from iPhoto. I take a lot of photos on my iPhone and have always imported, *then deleted* these using iPhoto. After importing photos from my photo with Aperture I didn't get an option to delete the originals from the phone. Am I missing a config option somewhere, or does Aperture not offer this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aperture does not seem to offer this functionality for the iPhone. So after importing it does not give you the option.

See picture here: [Aperture Import finished](http://k.min.us/jlQX3A.png)

But after importing you can always use `Image Capture` to delete the photos in one go:

See picture here: [Image Capture](http://k.min.us/jlQKGM.png)

Comment: Thanks, this is what I've been doing for a while now, so I'm accepting this as the only answer.